# How to remove linker error w.r.t. ltclcl in ns-2.29 installation?

Tags: ns2

I am trying to install ns-allinone-2.29 on Ubuntu 18.04. I need to implement Media Independent Handovers using the NIST-MIH patch. I have followed all instructions given in https://sourceforge.net/p/mihnistns229/wiki/Home/#74da. After I run the ./install command, I get the following error -

**/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /home/rajeshwari/ns-allinone-2.29/tclcl-1.17/libtclcl.a when searching for -ltclcl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltclcl**

Has anyone come across a similar problem?
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Note: A default ns-allinone-2.29. **3** .tar.gz can be built in Ubuntu 18.04, using  gcc, g++ version 4.1.2 ( but not with the NIST code ) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing ( gcc41-c++) ......... `$ export CC=gcc41 CXX=g++41 && ./install`

Answer (score 0):

> instructions ...
> https://sourceforge.net/p/mihnistns229/wiki/Home/#74da

The year 2013 "sourceforge.net/p/mihnistns229/wiki" recommends Ubuntu **8.04**! In 2013 (and later on) you could use the 32bit CentOS 6 - i386 for building "nist-mob", with g++34. (`compat-gcc-34-c++-3.4.6-19.el6.i686`)

If you have a later (32 or 64bits Ubuntu), you cannot build the year 2006 nist code. But you can install a nist app built with CentOS 6 : `nist-pmip6-ns_229-1-ubuntu12_i386.deb` (2.8MB)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6AFUAnSzay7gDLq1AzcySAQ9pFEGShr/view?usp=sharing .... Provides `/usr/local/bin/ns229-nist-pmip6-el6`

Ref. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNcEpiMmRyNTVndFE?resourcekey=0-bTnJ3S5xWfaoGPAjJEkwzg&usp=sharing (All ns2 binary rpm, deb packages.)

Simulation examples, nist-mob_examples-02.19.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TIkHH4Fr4IXiGzaw8DrPB9UT1zV8V4cT/view?usp=sharing

nist-mob INFO https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/nist-mob/ ... and https://groups.google.com/g/ns-users/search?q=nist-mob

About "NS-MIH-MULTI-CRITERIA" https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/ns-2-35-handoff-between-wifi-and-wimax-4175604225/#7

---

A more contemporary "wimax handover" is **ns2-802-16j-adaptive-quantum**  -  IEEE 802.16j Scheduling Algorithm with Adaptive Quantum - ns2 .
A scheduling algorithm developed for IEEE 802.16j module used on ns2.
This module is a ***WiMAX NIST based*** version improved for multihop relay support.

`wimax-OFDMA_ns231.patch, wimax-802-16j-OFDMA_ns233.patch, wimax-802-16j-OFDMA_ns235.patch` https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?usp=sharing

wimax-ex-all_10.2015.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZkx5bmJjZEYyVEE/view?usp=sharing

---

Old ns-2.29-nist-mob, 32bit CentOS 6.10 https://vault.centos.org/6.10/isos/i386/CentOS-6.10-i386-LiveDVD.iso .... and repo file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SCeRmo5mbbvzpVyBJcyfF69shD9Cr2IV/view?usp=sharing

```
# yum install gcc-c++ compat-gcc-34-c++ automake autoconf libtool libXmu-devel

$ tar xvf ns-allinone-2.29.3.tar.gz
$ cd ns-allinone-2.29/
$ tar xvf ns-2.29-nist-mob-022707.tgz
$ patch -p0 < pmip6-for-ns-2.29-nist.patch
$ export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && ./install
$ cd ns-2.29/
$ copy ns ns-nist
$ su
# copy ns-nist /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am able to run the NIST examples by installing the nist-pmip6-ns_229-ubuntu12_i386.deb package. But I want to modify some code to change the default working of the handover process. How can I do that?

Comment: Install ns2-802-16j-adaptive-quantum - IEEE 802.16j : May work with Ubuntu 18.04 . .... Old NIST ns-2.29-nist-mob-022707.tgz : 32bit CentOS 6.10 only ..... please see the edited answer.